# What part (success/error) of jquery's ajax receives a redirect status code?

Tags: javascript, jquery, redirect

I'm having a redirect sent by my server but jquery's ajax error: callback seems to get `xhr.status=200` and `status="parseerror"`

Anywork around?? I don't want to overload other codes since I use the for the things that they were intended for? Is this just not possible with jquery?

The callback is like this:
`error: function(xhr, status){...}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you redirect from the server you can send a response header along with it. And then look for that respone header in the ajax error/success callback. I hope that will help you

```
 var status =   xhr.getResponseHeader("redirectResponseHeader");//Specify the same name in the server side code
```

Now using `status` you can decide what to do.

Comment: Not helpful. That is what I am exactly doing. I want to know "how" to access the 302/3 codes and not how to show it. I have already said that I am getting a 200 status code even though the code should be 302

Comment: @Nupul - It was my bad, take a look at my edited answer hope that helps you, I think you can remove down vote now :)

Comment: Duly done :) quick question, what do you mean "same name" example? Do you mean a "custom" header? Isn't that against the spirit of REST/HTTP??

Comment: What ever name you specify on the server side, you should use the same while getting it.

Comment: :No no...I mean do I need to set custom headers or can use something already existing???

Comment: Does custom headers provide you redirect information? If yes, use them other wise create a new one.

Answer (score 0):

The redirect codes 301, 302, 303, and 307 are handled by the user agent, so you can't access the redirect code from the callback.
Reference: [XMLHttpRequest Level 2 spec](http://dev.w3.org/2006/webapi/XMLHttpRequest-2/#same-origin-request-event-rules)

Comment: I read the spec, but am still not clear as to why is that the case? I mean if I can't ever access these status codes then I'm always forced to 'hack' my around, is it?